# How to change two volume controls with amixer?

Tags: linux, bash, alsa

I'm trying to change the volume of two simple mixer controls via `amixer` in a bash shell.

Here's the version of ALSA I'm running:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k3.8.13-gentoo.
```

I have two simple mixer controls (`'DAC',0` and `'DAC',1`) which I'm interested in controlling:

```
$ amixer scontrols
...
Simple mixer control 'DAC',0
Simple mixer control 'DAC',1
...
```

I can easily set the volume of each control individually by using the `amixer set command`:

```
$ amixer set -c0 DAC,0 10%- && amixer set -c0 DAC,1 10%-
```

Although it works, executing `amixer` twice doesn't seem very eloquent to me. Is there a way to change the volume of multiple simple mixer controls using a *single* `amixer` execution?

Comment: Is this works ? `amixer set -c0 'DAC,0 10%-' && amixer set -c0 'DAC,1 10%-'`

Comment: @sputnick No, I'm looking for a solution using **one** amixer executation not two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass multiple commands through *stdin*:

```sh
amixer -c0 -sq <<-EOF
    set DAC,0 10%-
    set DAC,1 10%-
EOF
```